# textbooks on probability and statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I want a textbook on probability and statistics that's short , concise and easy to read that's written for mathematicians and physicists . I want it for my study of statistical mechanics

Answer (score 1):

**Intro to Probability and Statistics**,
Milton, J.Susan and J.C.Arnold,
TMH, $4th$ ed , $2003$

I have followed this book and I found it good enough.